# How to store IExtensibleDataObject into list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, web-services, methods

I want to call web services and store in `List` but not able to add i know the return type is not matching for both.
May i know how to consume web service and store in List.
I have class which inherit with object, `System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
Should I use LINQ.
```

Signature of GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow:

```
 public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.INITIATORS_LIST GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(string userId, string WorkflowTypeCode) {
            return base.Channel.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userId, WorkflowTypeCode);
        }
```

Refrence:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IMasterDataService/GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IMasterDataService/GetInitiatorsListByWorkflowResponse")]
        [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.CustomFaultException), Action="http://tempuri.org/IMasterDataService/GetInitiatorsListByWorkflowCustomFaultExcep" +
            "tionFault", Name="CustomFaultException", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Almarai.Web.Services.MasterData")]
        Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.INITIATORS_LIST GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(string userId, string WorkflowTypeCode);
```

My class :

```
public partial class INITIATORS_LIST : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

            [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
            private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
            private Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COMPANY_M[] CompaniesField;

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
            private Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COUNTRY_M[] CountriesField;

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
            private Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_DIVISION_M[] DivisionsField;

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
            private Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.LOCATION[] LocationsField;

            [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
            public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.extensionDataField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.extensionDataField = value;
                }
            }

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
            public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COMPANY_M[] Companies
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.CompaniesField;
                }
                set
                {
                    if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.CompaniesField, value) != true))
                    {
                        this.CompaniesField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Companies");
                    }
                }
            }

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
            public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COUNTRY_M[] Countries
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.CountriesField;
                }
                set
                {
                    if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.CountriesField, value) != true))
                    {
                        this.CountriesField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Countries");
                    }
                }
            }

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
            public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_DIVISION_M[] Divisions
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.DivisionsField;
                }
                set
                {
                    if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.DivisionsField, value) != true))
                    {
                        this.DivisionsField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Divisions");
                    }
                }
            }

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
            public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.LOCATION[] Locations
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.LocationsField;
                }
                set
                {
                    if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.LocationsField, value) != true))
                    {
                        this.LocationsField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Locations");
                    }
                }
            }

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
            public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.REGION[] Regions
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.RegionsField;
                }
                set
                {
                    if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.RegionsField, value) != true))
                    {
                        this.RegionsField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Regions");
                    }
                }
            }

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
            public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_WKFLW_TYPE_M[] WorkflowTypes
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.WorkflowTypesField;
                }
                set
                {
                    if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.WorkflowTypesField, value) != true))
                    {
                        this.WorkflowTypesField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("WorkflowTypes");
                    }
                }
            }

            public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
                if ((propertyChanged != null))
                {
                    propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
        }
```

My method:

```
  [WebMethod]
        public static List<INITIATORS_LIST> GetCountriesName(string UserID)
        {
            GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient();
           
            List<INITIATORS_LIST> lst  = new List<INITIATORS_LIST>();

            var INITIATORS_LIST = new INITIATORS_LIST()
            {
                ExtensionData =
                oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow("SAU", "SaudiArebia")//Error on this Line
            };
            return lst;
        }
```

Comment: Please post `GetActiveCountries` signature.

Comment: @Dennis Please check my updated Code